# Can “dire” be used as “so-called”?

Tags: vocabulaire, passif, participe-passé

> [Dans des diocèses dits ruraux](http://www.la-croix.com/Religion/Actualite/L-Eglise-que-veut-le-pape-Francois-2013-07-30-992764)

Can *dire* in this context be translated as *so-called*: *in the so-called rural dioceses*?

Comment: Please read up on the meaning of *grammaire/grammar*. It doesn't mean whatever you think it means. This question, like many others that you tag [tag:grammar], has nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dits* dans ce cas est un adjectif, pluriel de *dit*.

Il est généralement employé afin de remplacer *appelé* ou *nommé* comme dans :

> André *dit* Dédé (André also known as Dédé)

Dans le cas précis de la phrase :

> Dans des diocèses dits ruraux

*Dits* est utilisé afin de préciser le type de diocèse dont on parle afin de les différencier des diocèses urbains. Dans cette situation *dit* peut effectivement être traduit par *so-called*.

*Dit* peut également être employé afin de mentionner un moment qui a été précisé à l'avance comme dans :

> Il est venu à l'heure *dite*.
>   Elle était présente le jour *dit*

Comment: Pourquoi adjectif ?  C'est un participe passé qui n'a pas acquis de sens supplémentaire par rapport au verbe (p.e. _Ces diocèses que je dis ruraux, ce sont ..._)

Comment: _Dit_ peut être un nom, le participe passé de dire ainsi qu'un adjectif. Dans la phrase _Dans des diocèses dits ruraux_ il s'agit bien de l'adjectif qui signifie _nommé_, _appelé_ ou _surnommé_. Dans la phrase _les faits et les dits_ le nom _dit_ signifie _ce qui a été dit_.

Comment: _Dit_ lie un objet (diocèse) à un attribut (ruraux) en donnant la nature de la liaison, c'est une fonction d'un verbe et non d'un adjectif, on peut d'ailleurs former des phrases similaires pour les autres formes verbales (j'en ai donné un exemple dans le premier commentaire).

Answer (score 0):

Beware, it can express a **doubt** :

"Ce boucher vend de la viande dite de bœuf" (= I believe it is horse-meat)

Or an **alias** (fraudulent or not), or a **nickname** :

"Jean Valjean, dit Monsieur Madeleine, ..."

"Pierre Dupont, dit Superman, ..."

Comment: I really don't feel like this answers the question at all; it's more of an fyi to the OP.

Comment: If you don't use quotes around *de bœuf* (even in speech) nobody would understand your implications. The rest was already mentioned in a previous and actual answer.